# How do I format data in a template using a *ngFor loop without having functions in the template?

Tags: angular, angular-template

Using Angular 11, I have a Component that receives an array of data from elsewhere. I want to display the data in a template using a `*ngFor` loop with custom formatting. Ideally I would use a function to format the data, but having a function in a template causes performance issues. What is the best way to format data in a template with a `*ngFor` loop?

For example, this template works but does not use best practices. (Note: the format is just an example. I'm looking for a general answer, not a DatePipe solution)

```js
class UserExample {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    loginTime: Date;
}

@Component({
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="user of userData; trackBy: trackRow">
            <h1>Name: {{ user.name }}</h1>
            <p>Hours: {{ getHours(user.loginTime) }}</p>
            <p>Milliseconds: {{ getMilliseconds(user.loginTime) }}</p>
        </div>
    `
})
export class ExampleComponent {
    @Input() userData: UserExample[] = [];

    public getHours(loginTime: Date): string {
        return loginTime.getHours().toString();
    }

    public getMilliseconds(loginTime: Date): string {
        return loginTime.getMilliseconds().toString();
    }

    public trackRow(index: number, item: UserExample): number {
        return item.id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular's DatePipe. Try below code :

```
@Component({
      template: `
        <div *ngFor="let user of userData; trackBy: trackRow">
          <h1>Name: {{ user.name }}</h1>
          <p>Hours: {{ user.loginTime | date: "hh" }}</p>
          <p>Milliseconds: {{ user.loginTime | date: "SSS" }}</p>
        </div>
      `
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables and assign them to the functions and then use those variables in the template. Something like this:

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="user of userData; trackBy: trackRow">
            <h1>Name: {{ user.name }}</h1>
            <p *ngIf="loginHours">Hours: {{ loginHours }}</p>
            <p *ngIf="loginMilliSeconds">
               Milliseconds: {{ loginMilliSeconds }}
            </p>
        </div>
    `
})
export class ExampleComponent {
    @Input() userData: UserExample[] = [];

   public loginHours = getHours(userData.loginTime);

   public loginMilliSeconds = getMilliseconds(userData.loginTime);

     getHours(loginTime: Date): string {
        return loginTime.getHours().toString();
     }
     getMilliseconds(loginTime: Date): string {
        return loginTime.getMilliseconds().toString();
     }

     public trackRow(index: number, item: UserExample): number {
        return item.id;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Pipe` which you can use for executing any function in template

```
@Pipe({name: 'execute'})
export class ExecutePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(fn: (...args: any[]) => any, ...args: any[]): any {
    return fn(...args);
  }

}
```

First argument of this Pipe is the function, and the rest are arguments for the function

```
<p>Hours: {{ getHours | execute: user.loginTime }}</p>
<p>Milliseconds: {{ getMilliseconds | execute: user.loginTime }}</p>
```

This Pipe is pure, so it will be only be executed when one of its arguments changes